# Why does Linux stack area have executable protection?

Tags: linux, stack, virtual-memory

While studying the Linux kernel, I just found out that, by default, an executable has an 'executable' stack area. I naturally thought the only (necessary) executable area is the text section. Is there any historical reason related to this, or any practical usage?

Comment: GCC's nested functions are implemented as trampolines and require an executable stack. There are other use cases, some of them described [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/Roadmap/ExecutableStacks).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Executable stack is necessary in some cases such as GCC trampoline for nested functions.

A trampoline is a small piece of code that is created at run time when the address of a nested function is taken. It normally resides on the stack, in the stack frame of the containing function. These macros tell GCC how to generate code to allocate and initialize a trampoline.

In most distros because of attack risks and use of stack to execute a shellcode this functionality is disables, although you can compile a code with `-z execstack` to enable it. It's also possible to use a program called `execstack` to enable or disable this feature after compiling the program. To make this clear I wrote a simple program to execute `exit` syscall with the exit code of 32. If this feature is enabled the code works, otherwise it gives segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char shellCode[] =  "\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00" //          mov    $0x1,%eax
                    "\xbb\x20\x00\x00\x00" //          mov    $0x20,%ebx
                    "\xcd\x80";            //          int $0x80

int main(){
    int *ret;
    ret = (int*) &ret + 2;
    *ret = (int) shellCode;
    return 5;
}
```

In this code `ret` is pointing to it's address plus 2. As we know in IA32 systems pointer size is 4bytes and at the beginning of each function there is a `push ebp` after compilation. So in order to reach return address of `main` we need to add `2*stack_chunk_size` and by setting each chunk 4byte at compile time this works perfectly.

Compile the code like this to test:

```
gcc -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -z execstack -o testShellCode testShellCode.c
```

`-mpreferred-stack-boundary=2` is to align stack in 4 bytes chunks and `-z execstack` is to compile using executable stack.

This simple code can give some insight into the reason why there is such a thing as executable stack protection.

Look up the following links for more information on nested functions and `execstack` command:

[Trampolines](http://linux.die.net/man/8/execstack)

[execstack](http://linux.die.net/man/8/execstack)

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect but that's quite a story. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well on the second though about the example, shouldn't the control be transferred to the data section after the return statement in 'main'? I think the example makes sense if 'shellCode' was declared in a function scope.